# Open a file while ignoring case in the path and filename

Tags: c#, .net, case-insensitive

I can convert `pathAndFilename` to lower case, but its like I need a way to tell `OpenRead` to be case-insenstiive.

```
// pathAndFileName has been converted with .ToLower()
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(pathAndFileName))
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fileStream);
    Image image = (Image)bitmap;
}
```

Comment: On Windows, it is already case insensitive. Are you sure you have a problem with case?

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but it is accessing a network drive which is apparently case-sensitive

Comment: there is `Image.FromFile` Method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile. It uses `Path.GetFullPath` to get the path

Comment: Well, if the storage medium is case-sensitive you have to use the original spelling.

Comment: Network drive paths are also not case sensitive in Windows. Why do you think case sensitivity is the issue? What is the specific error message you're getting, and what is the actual value of `pathAndFileName`?

Comment: @Slai: I see nothing in that doc discussing case sensitivity.

Comment: You have proposed a solution but not described the problem. What is actual versus expected behavior? What error message are you receiving?

Comment: Why do you use ToLower() on the filename instead of using the original spelling?

Comment: @NineBerry: it was halfway to getting both sides the same. I'm trying your solution below. If that works, then obviously I don't need `ToLower()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to access files on a machine running Linux or some other operating system where file names are case sensitive, a workaround could be (not tested!) to use the filename you have as a pattern to list the files in the directory. Be aware that there can be multiple files with the same name and just different spelling variants. This helper function will raise an exception in this case.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pathAndFileName = ..your file name...;
    string resultFileName = GetActualCaseForFileName(pathAndFileName);

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(resultFileName))
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fileStream);
        Image image = (Image)bitmap;
    }    


    Console.WriteLine(resultFileName);
}

private static string GetActualCaseForFileName(string pathAndFileName)
{
    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathAndFileName);
    string pattern = Path.GetFileName(pathAndFileName);
    string resultFileName;

    // Enumerate all files in the directory, using the file name as a pattern
    // This will list all case variants of the filename even on file systems that
    // are case sensitive
    IEnumerable<string> foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, pattern);

    if (foundFiles.Any())
    {
        if (foundFiles.Count() > 1)
        {
            // More than two files with the same name but different case spelling found
            throw new Exception("Ambiguous File reference for " + pathAndFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            resultFileName = foundFiles.First();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found" + pathAndFileName, pathAndFileName);
    }

    return resultFileName;
}
```

Comment: This was a great idea, but unfortunately, for me, Directory.EnumerateFiles() and it's cousin, GetFiles(), does NOT do a case insensitive search.

Comment: @bobwki You can specify an additional argument of Type EnumerationOptions to use case-insensitive search on Linux.

Comment: Did not know that -- I should've mentioned that I only checked for iOS.

Comment: I did not find anything like that in options -- yes, it would be convenient if those options were there.

Comment: @bobwki Oh, you are talking about xamarin. The `EnumerationOptions` option is available in .net core. It will take some time until it's available in xamarin.

Answer (score 2):

I was inspired by the answer that included GetActualCaseForFileName(), but it did not work for my Xamarin iOS project.

I created the following code, which seems to work for me:

```
public string getCaseNudgedPathName( string origPath) {
    var retPath = origPath;
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName( origPath);
    var pattern = Path.GetFileName( origPath);

    var foundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
    int countMatch = 0;
    foreach (var foundFile in foundFiles) {
        if ( foundFile.Equals(origPath,IgnoreCase)) {
            countMatch++;
            retPath = foundFile;
        }
    }
    if (countMatch > 1) { 
        throw new Exception( $"Ambiguous filename '{pattern}'");
    } 
    return retPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For file and directory case sensitive you need a combination of the first answer and:

```
private static string GetActualCaseForFileName(string pathAndFileName)
{
    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathAndFileName);
    string directoryCaseSensitive = GetDirectoryCaseSensitive(directory)
    ...
}


private static string GetDirectoryCaseSensitive(string directory)
{
  var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
  if (directoryInfo.Exists)
  {
    return directory;
  }

  if (directoryInfo.Parent == null)
  {
    return null;
  }

  var parent = GetDirectoryCaseSensitive(directoryInfo.Parent.FullName);
  if (parent == null)
  {
    return null;
  }

  return new DirectoryInfo(parent).GetDirectories(directoryInfo.Name, new EnumerationOptions {MatchCasing = MatchCasing.CaseInsensitive}).FirstOrDefault()?.FullName;
}
```